# Is it necessary to reboot computer after changes in system variables?

Tags: windows-7, jvm

I change JDK path and JAVA_HOME in system variables from one to another and after that, I open cmd and try:

```
java -version
```

and the result of version not change to another JDK.

If my memory doesn't fail me before I used changes without reboot, so that is why I ask this question.
Maybe it's necessary to restart JVM? How can I do it without a reboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Windows, *new* processes pick up environment variable changes right away.

However, your problem probably has nothing to do with environment variables. The Windows version of JRE puts executables like `java.exe`, `javaw.exe` in the system32 folder, so unless you have your JDK before `%windir%\system32` in your PATH, you'll always be running the JRE.

I would normally delete those ones in system32 and make my path point to the correct JVM installation.